# kannel gateway is not answering SMS

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, smpp, kannel

I'm trying to set up a kannel gateway that connects to a server, it receives SMS messages (that's already working) and it has to answer "OK".

But I'm not even seeing an error in the log related with the outgoing message.

This is my kannel.conf. I see in the log that I get the messages but it seems kannel is not trying to send anything.

```
group = core
admin-port = 13000
smsbox-port = 13001
admin-password = <mypass>
log-file = "/tmp/kannel.log"
log-level = 0
box-deny-ip = "*.*.*.*"
box-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1"

group=smsc
smsc=smpp
smsc-id=personal
interface-version=34
host=<smpp-host>
port=5016
system-id=<smpp-username>
smsc-username=<smpp-username>
smsc-password=<smpp-password>
system-type=default
transceiver-mode = yes
my-number = <my-number>

group=smsc
smsc=smpp
smsc-id=personal
interface-version=34
host=<smpp-host>
port=5016
system-id=<smpp-username>
smsc-username=<smpp-username>
smsc-password=<smpp-password>
system-type=default
transceiver-mode = yes
log-file = /tmp/smsc.log
my-number = <my-number>

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
sendsms-port = 13013
log-level = 0

group = sms-service
keyword = default
text = "OK"
catch-all = true
omit-empty = true
max-messages = 0
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I missunderstand anything in the documentation?
Am I reading the incorrect log?

Thanks in advance

Comment: smsbox has it's own logs, you should add log-file and access-log directives in the smsbox group and check those logs.

Comment: add accepted-smsc = personal

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration

```
group = sms-service
keyword = default
text = "OK"
catch-all = true
omit-empty = true
max-messages = 0
accepted-smsc = personal
#omit-empty = true
#max-messages = 100
```